# Sequence to carry out data analysis?

Tags: data-mining, predictive-modeling, class-imbalance

I have a dataset with 4700 records and it's a classification problem. Proportion of classes is 33 and 67%

few questions

1) does this proportion qualify dataset as imbalanced ?

2) should I do cross validation and then apply (over/under or SMOTE sampling)  or I should first balance my sample through these sampling techniques and then do cross validation?

3) Why is propensity score matching used only in healthcare related studies and not much in other applications?

4) How is Propensity score matching different from other ML classification algorithms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fit preprocessing transformers, i.e. imputation, scalers, encoders, resampling, only to train set and apply them to both train and test respectively. Your dataset is imbalanced and you may expect some improvement using resampling techniques, though you should always confirm it conducting cross validation tests.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Just to make sure I got it right. You are asking me to do sampling (over or under or SMOTE) to the full dataset and achieve a balance in my dataset. Once this is done, do cross validation. Have I understood it right?

Comment: upvoted your answer

Comment: What do you mean by train and apply them to both train and test in below sentence `only to train set and apply them to both train and test respectively. `

Comment: On the contrary, first you split, fit transformers on train set and then apply them on both train and test. That's basically why you need to use pipeline for [imblearn](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) instead of `sklearn` one.

Comment: can we break this into simple points. Might be I am struggling to understand due to language proficiency

Comment: 1) Have an imbalanced dataset in a csv 2) Do preprocessing work like encoders, standard scalars 3) Apply resampling techniques to balance the dataset (it becomes balanced) 4) Split the dataset into 70% train and 30% test 5)  Apply the model on train set 6) fit it on Test dataset

Comment: Have I got it right?

Comment: Nope ;P First split, then resample train set. Don't resample test set.

Comment: Hi,  okay.  But in this as we aren't resamplin test set, Will it contain equal proportion of classes?  Or is your idea like since we have resampled train data, it would have seen enough variations in data for both classes which makes model knolwdegeable to distinguish both the classes in test data (irrespective of the proportion of classes).  Am I right?

Comment: Over-sampled train set will be balanced. Training model on imbalanced data results in overfitting to over-represented classes.  I'd use stratified splits as well. What metrics will you use to score your models?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102018/discussion-between-ssmk-and-piotr-rarus-reinstate-monica).

Comment: Can you help me with this? https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/64756/how-to-select-features-for-a-ml-model